# Minimum Order Amount Notification

Tags: checkout

I currently have 2 payment methods Terms & Credit Card Saved (only available to a my wholesale customer group) that I have $150 minimum order threshold set. However, if a customer from that group gets to checkout with an order less than $150, it doesn't show a notification or anything telling them to order more, it just leaves the payment field blank (doesn't offer any methods) and the customer gets confused.

I use a one-step checkout module from magestore.com and was told to place the message into  and to have it check the subtotal before showing the message.

Unfortunately that's a little over my head with php.

Anyone have insight on how to implement this or suggest any other methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The magestore onestepcheckout is a paid extension so I don't have access to the code. But I'll try to point you in the right direction.

First you need to find the phtml file that displays the payment methods. You can do this by enabling the template hints in the admin `System > Configuration > [Scope set to website] > Developer` and set `Template Path Hints` to **yes**

Refresh the index which will show you the path of the phtml file. Open the file in an editor and add something like this

```
$quote = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
$customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
if ($quote->getSubtotal() < 150 && $customer->getGroupId() == 3) {
   echo "Dude... you gotta order mo stuff";
}
```

Comment: Hey Sander, Thanks for the response to this. What would I need to add to that to where it only looks at a certain customer group? This only needs to apply to 1 group.

Comment: updated the answer to include customer group

Comment: Hey Sander, circling back to this. I found the phtml file displaying the payment methods, do I just dump that code into the file wherever, or does it need to be enclosed in a php statement?

Comment: @EricFox jup, should be enclosed as PHP